# LG G4 not restarting

Tags: adb, boot, boot-loop, lg-g4

My device is rooted. It was working fine for months. But suddenly it struck and now its not restarting back. It struck at LG logo. I have no idea why its happening.

Also, it is rebooting again and again to LG logo. I don't wanna factory reset as I have have too many apps installed on the device and don't even know the names of all those apps. Is there any way through ADB that I can get the list of installed apps(without restarting) and then I can hard factory reset?

Comment: I do not understand why you're asking for a solution which requires ADB. If the device can't get past the boot logo, then it means that Android OS is not in a condition to launch and run ADB daemon in the device (I even wonder whether OS itself is initialized by that time) which implies that `adb devices` would give you nothing. Instead, simply ask for a way to get the installed apps' name. Also, there is nothing termed *hard factory reset*: there is [tag:factory-reset] and separately, the [tag:hard-reset].

Comment: I did factory reset and hard reset both. The phone starts and them again its gets into bootloop @Firelord

Answer (score 0):

You can view all the apps by going to My Apps in the Google Play Store, and selecting the "All" tab. Although, this will also show all apps you have ever installed.

Comment: @SarpSTA You can view it from the new phone. For instance, I can view apps I installed on my old android (cyanogenmod) tablet from my N5.

Comment: This method is much easier, as you can easily reinstall them, and you don't have to go hunting for the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Some users have reported this loop which looks like a hardware problem if its persistent.

However, your best option would be to hard reset your LG G4. No one loves starting from the scratch but you often get frustrated from the phone being frozen most of the time. At this point, you have to detach your emotions and apply technical logic which will solve the problem.

If you are not sure about a hard reset just yet, you can try a soft reset that involves removing the battery and inserting it back after 1-mins.

If that fails, you really have to perform a factory reset. You can try any of the methods in this guide to [hard reset your LG G4](http://www.techrez.com/lg-g4-factory-reset/).

Comment: It's a hardware issue. Got the hardware fixed multiple times still there's a problem. Sold the device